# FCM data payload notification doesn't open the mentioned activity

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-push-notification

I know this is asked a million times before and I have tried everything I saw but I just cant make it work. I have data payload notification. Am getting them in *onMessageReceived()* but when I click the notification in notification tray it doesn't redirect to the launcher.

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LandingActivity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", data.toString());
        resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);


            // image is present, show notification with image
           //showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, "13", resultIntent, profilePicThumb); 
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, LandingActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                    .setContentText("my message")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

and ***LandingActivity***  is the launcher activity of my app.

my manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".landing.LandingActivity_"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When notification_payload with optional data_payload was given I got data in LandingActivity but when I get only data_payload the click redriection doesnt happen

the data-payload structure is like this

```
"data" :
{
"notification_type"   : "QUIZ_WINNER", 
"notification_message": "You hav won the quiz ",
"notification_data"   : [
        "user_id"          : id,
        "full_name"        : full_name,
        "profile_pic_thumb": user_profile_picthumb,
        'quiz_id'          : quiz_id,
        'question_id'      : question_id,
        'quiz_title'       : quiz_title,
    ],
"user_id"             : from_id,
'notification_to'     : to_id,
'created_at'          : date,
'updated_at'          : date,
```

}

I am able to receive notification but I cannot open the LandingActivity

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

***FINAL ANSWER***

Finally I got it working..I was using android annotations throught my project. The activity which I need to open was also annotated. Hence instead of this line of code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LandingActivity.class);
```

i added this

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, LandingActivity_.class);`

Hope it will be useful for someone at sometime.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the function showNotificationMessage and a sample of the payload, both with and without the optional data.

Comment: @JudeFernandes please see my post. I have added the payload. showNotificationMessage() is not used any more

Comment: Hi @suja Do add in an answer. Self-answering is highly encouraged here in Stack Overflow. I see that you added one earlier, you could just go ahead and undelete it, then accept it after a few hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

At the line you are setting 'Pending Intent', you should use a request code other than zero. It fixed my problem. I hope it will fix your problem too.

```
int requestCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```